# How to run new exterior A/C drain line

Tags: water, air-conditioning, pipe, drainage

I'm trying to replace my A/C drain pipe. It was draining into an old PVC pipe contraption that did nothing - water was leaking all over the brick and foundation.

I pushed the PVC to the side and connected the drain line to a 10 foot clear vinyl tube from Home Depot - [UDP 1 in. I.D. x 1-1/4 in. O.D. x 10 ft. Clear Vinyl Tubing](https://www.homedepot.com/p/304185179).

Note that there are two metal drain lines coming out of the brick wall. The top one does not have any water exiting it - it's only the bottom drain line with the clear vinyl tube attached.
The distance from the drain line to the edge of the concrete is around 12 feet. The 10 foot tube I installed isn't long enough to reach, so I ran if off to the side. While the water does drain into the pine straw successfully, there is standing water in the middle of the tube at its lowest altitude.

Should I return this 10 foot tube and buy a 12 foot tube and run it to the edge of the concrete? If so, is there anything I should connect the end of the tube to? Or is there a completely better approach? I'm completely new to this and have no idea what I'm doing.

[image: The old PVC drain was leaking water all over the brick and foundation so I replaced it with a clear vinyl tube secured with a zip tie]
The old PVC drain was leaking water all over the brick and foundation so I replaced it with a clear vinyl tube secured with a zip tie

[image: The 10 foot clear vinyl tube runs out to the pine straw]
The 10 foot clear vinyl tube runs out to the pine straw

[image: There is standing water in the middle of the tube at its lowest altitude]
There is standing water in the middle of the tube at its lowest altitude

[image: This tube is only 10 feet, but I could buy a 12 foot minimum tube and just run it directly into the pine straw at the edge of the concrete]
This tube is only 10 feet, but I could buy a 12 foot minimum tube and just run it directly into the pine straw at the edge of the concrete

[image: The water is draining into the pine straw]
The water is draining into the pine straw

Comment: I don't think you should return the 10 ft length of tubing. You have used it, and it can not be resold. Keep it; you may use it sometime. If you want a 12 ft tube, go buy that.

Comment: Or buy a couple of more feet...you should be able to splice the two hoses.